using javascript modules in Blazor
I would like to organize javascript code in modules in Blazor.
I followed some javascript tutos on this topic, but it is not to working in blazor.
Here is a simple example.
Starting from a blazor template, I have added 2 js files.

main.js contains:
function Increment(value) {
value++;
DisplayVal(value);
return value;}

module1.js contains:
function DisplayVal(value) {
console.log("The value is " + value);}

In the counter page I have added
@inject IJSRuntime JS
and
private async Task IncrementCount()
{
    //currentCount++;
    currentCount = await JS.InvokeAsync<int>("Increment", currentCount);
}

In the index.html I have added
<script src="/Scripts/main.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/module1.js" autostart="false"></script>

So far everything is working.
Now I want to convert module1.js in a module.
I add the export tag
export function DisplayVal(value) {
    console.log("The value is " + value);
}

In main. js I add
import { DisplayVal } from "./module1.js"

And in index.html I change as follows:
<script type="module" src="/Scripts/main.js" autostart="false"></script>
<!--<script src="/Scripts/module1.js" autostart="false"></script>-->

Now I get the followin error:

How can I make it work?

You have to async-Import the Module, e.g.:
let jsModule = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/Scripts/module1.js"); 
await jsModule.InvokeAsync("Increment", currentCount);

For more information, consult their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules

The main script needs to be a module, and imported in Blazor.  The sub-module can be imported in js.  The script reference in index.html / app.razor can be ommitted
var jsMain = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/Scripts/main.js");
currentCount = await jsMain.InvokeAsync<int>("Increment", currentCount);

main.js
import { DisplayVal } from "./module1.js"

export function Increment(value) {
    value++;
    DisplayVal(value);
    return value;
}

